# SSIS Catalog deployment not creating symmetric keys

Tags: ssis

I am having a problem with a SSIS Project in the SSIS Catalog. When I schedule the package to run, I get an "Unexpected Termination" error.

If I look in the event viewer, I get the following error:
The SSIS Execution Process could not write to the IS catalog: SERVER:SSISDB Error details: Cannot find the symmetric key 'MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_13', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

If I check sys.symmetric_keys, this key does not exist.
If I check sys.certificates, I can see a certificate name MS_Cert_Proj_13, but no certificate named MS_Cert_Proj_Param_13.

We have recently upgrade the servers to SQL 2014 CU4 from SQL2012.  All the other projects that are working fine were created on SQL2012 and uploaded then.  This is the first project deployed since the upgrade.

I have created a new solution, recreated the parameters and copied the package into this solution.  I then built this and deployed it with the same results.

Any one seen similar or know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restore the 2012 SSISDB to the 2014 instance?

Comment: Nope, we did an in place upgrade.

Comment: I'll see if I can find documentation, but my memory says they don't support anything but a fresh installation of the SSISDB and an Export/Import of packages and configurations.

Comment: I think I have solved the issue. The upgrade leaves version 11 of the SSIS service in place and installs the new ssis service. The old service requires both symmetric keys, but the new 2014 service only needs the one. The packages were trying to run under the old service so they failed.  I uninstalled the ssis catalog (basically detached the DB), then created a new catalog and redeployed my packages.  Everything is working fine now.

Comment: Awesome. Post that down into the answer block and click the green checkmark

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the issue. The upgrade leaves version 11 of the SSIS service in place and installs the new ssis service. The old service requires both symmetric keys, but the new 2014 service only needs the one. The packages were trying to run under the old service so they failed. I uninstalled the ssis catalog (basically detached the DB), then created a new catalog and redeployed my packages. Everything is working fine now